# Approach to free poker sites

Tags: poker-strategy

What strategy to apply to free poker sites?

If they are free then winning does not mean much but how do you win more chips even if the chips have no cash value?

Furthermore, how do you not lose chips?  They give you some to start but then want you to pay for more chips if you run out.

For example playwsop.com

Answer (score 2):

A while ago there was a rant question here that wsop is rigged.  The assertions to me were pretty wild so I figured I would check it out.

As you can imagine very loose

Often everyone will see a flop so getting odds to play suited connectors
Other than that only play premium hands

They are not exactly fish but it is free and they want to play
Post flop play is more realistic than pre flop

The more expensive tournaments are better players and more realistic play
Still loose
Wait for premium hands as you get paid off

They like straight and flush draws and for the most part cannot get them off with even a pot sized bet.  Bet the pot to get money in the pot.  If the straight or flush hits and they bet then get away.

Not worth bluffing very often as not easy to get them to fold.  And you don't need to bluff to get action when you get a hand.

Raise pre flop with a premium hand to get money in the pot but don't expect a lot of folds

Play connectors if you can get in cheap as you can get paid off.  They either don't see it or don't care.  Also can typically get paid off with flush so I play any suited ace.

By the time you get down to heads up the blinds are big enough that it just gets down to luck.

AA, KK, QQ, AK just push as you will get called from a wide range

For the most part just ABC poker.

Oh, and I saw zero evidence that wsop is rigged.